# How to patch source code tree from within the dir to be modified?

Tags: diff, source, patch

A source code tree contains a modified dnsmasq-2.80test4 source (and git files).

Now I'd like to apply the newest 2.86 dnsmasq source code to that modified 2.80test4 using `diff` and `patch`, while working in the users home folder.

So I start copying .../dnsmasq-2.80test4 to the users home dir, and
create the diff file using:

```
~$ diff -urN ./dnsmasq-2.80test4 ./dnsmasq-2.86 > dnsmasq-2.86.diff
```

Then I'm trying to patch the old `~/dnsmasq-2.80test4` folder using:

```
~$ cd ./dnsmasq-2.80test4
~$ patch --dry-run -i ../dnsmasq-2.86.diff
```

which runs ok for CHANGELOG, FAQ, Makefile and Version. First file `Android.mk` in subdir `bld` fails, which is not a big deal. The real deal breaker is the second file in the same subdir:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 466
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -ur ./dnsmasq-2.80test4/bld/get-version ./dnsmasq-2.86/bld/get-version
|--- ./dnsmasq-2.80test4/bld/get-version    2022-07-03 17:32:08.541879257 +0200
|+++ ./dnsmasq-2.86/bld/get-version 2021-09-08 22:21:22.000000000 +0200
--------------------------
```

#### Workaround

When changing the working directory to one level up and renaming the newer /dnsmasq-2.86 source directory to a different name (or just removing it), the patch seems to be correctly applied to the old /dnsmasq-2.80test4 dir using:

```
~$ patch --dry-run --verbose -p0 -i dnsmasq-2.86.diff
```

#### Question

How to modify the `diff` and/or `patch` commands, allowing me to `patch` from within the directory that needs to changed (`cd ./parent/dnsmasq-2.80test4`) as working directory, instead of working from `cd ./parent` dir?

Comment: This sounds like a great example of where working with `git` would make things easier to manage (have your custom changes in branch off the 2.80test4 tag, rebase them onto 2.86, resolve conflicts, etc).

Comment: Even without git, you'd be better off generating a diff of your custom modified dnsmasq 2.80 versus official upstream 2.80, then try to apply that patch to 2.86.  There'll probably still be conflicts to resolve but your custom patch is likely to be a lot small than the diff between 2.80 and 2.86, so merging will be a lot less work.